# Is $(x+1, y+1)$ a proper ideal of $\mathbb{C}[x,y]$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, ideals

It feels like the answer should be obvious. It seems clear that $(x+1,y+1)\neq\mathbb{C}[x,y]$ should be the case, but I am having a surprising amount of difficulty showing it rigorously.

Comment: The shortest way: consider the homomorphism $\mathbb C[x, y] \to \mathbb C$ which sends $x$ and $y$ both to $-1$. The easiest way: for any $\alpha, \beta \in C[x,y]$ we have that $(x+1)\alpha + (y+1)\beta$ has degree at least $1$.

Comment: Thank you. The shortest way makes sense to me. Since some elements (such as x+2) don't map to 0, the kernel must be a proper ideal of $\mathbb{C}[x,y]$ which clearly contains $(x+1,y+1)$. I don't quite follow the easiest way however. I see immediately that $\deg{(x+1)\alpha}\geq 1$ and $\deg{(y+1)\beta}\geq 1$, but I don't see how that implies $\deg{(x+1)\alpha+(y+1)\beta}\geq 1$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a cute proof. Suppose that it's not proper, i.e. there are polynomials $f$ and $g$ such that 
$$(x+1)f(x,y)+(y+1)g(x,y)=1$$
Substitute $x=y$ to obtain:
$$(x+1)(f(x,x)+g(x,x))=1$$
but the left hand side is either $0$ or has at least degree 1.

Comment: This is a lovely, intuitive proof - but I do remember always feeling a little cheated by proofs like this as a beginner. There's a lot being swept under the carpet here: why can we "substitute" $x=y$ at all? (This works precisely because there's a ring homomorphism $\mathbb{C}[x,y] \to \mathbb{C}[x]$ sending both $x$ and $y$ to $x$, plus the isomorphism theorems.) Why does "degree" make sense? (You have to check that both of these rings *admit* a notion of degree, and that the ring homomorphism above *respects* these notions - i.e. that this is actually a homomorphism of *graded* rings.) etc.

Comment: I agree it's simplifying a little but it's also not exactly a coincidence that there's such a homomorphism. The universal property of polynomial rings is the existence of arbitrary evaluation homomorphisms, i.e. the defining property of a polynomial ring is exactly that we can just make substitutions like $x=y$. There's also no issue with the degree since we only bring that up once we've reached the single-variable case (indeed, evaluating $y=x$ doesn't respect degrees).